# loop over array of objects based on the keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, object

Sort the array of objects by the certain order.

```
var details = [{
"name": "john",
"place":"new york"
},{
"name": "mark",
"place":"chicago"
},{
"name": "tom",
"place":"san jose"
},{
"name": "dansk",
"place":"new jersey"
}],
```

The map should show a list in following order, basically we need to decide the pattern of output, we should be able to change the order:

```
san jose,
new york,
chicago,
new jersey
```

I tried this:

```
details.sort((a, b)=> a.place - b.place)).map((data) => {
return(
 <div>
   <li>{data.place}</li>
 </div>
)})
```

Comment: what do you expect the result of `"string" - "string"` is? - try using the string `localeCompare` method

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you point out a rule by which you compare two strings in this case? It is impossible to write a program without knowing the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For sort array based on other Array, you can you this code

```js
var details = [{
    "name": "john",
    "place": "new york"
}, {
    "name": "mark",
    "place": "chicago"
}, {
    "name": "tom",
    "place": "san jose"
}, {
    "name": "dansk",
    "place": "new jersey"
}];

var sortingArray = ["san jose", "new york", "chicago", "new jersey"];


var result = [];



sortingArray.forEach(function (key) {
    var found = false;
    details = details.filter(function (item) {
        if (!found && item.place == key) {
            result.push(item);
            found = true;
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    })
})

console.log(result);
```

After rearranging array you can map

```
result.map((data) => {
   return (
       <div>
           <li>{data.place}</li>
       </div>
   )
})
```

Comment: this will give in alphabetical order, but we need in mentioned order like san jose,
new york,
chicago,
new jersey

Comment: what kind of order? this do you another array of order like this ["san jose", "new york", "chicago", "new jersey"]?

Comment: @Mark  I have updated my code in answered. Please check.

Comment: @Mark Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any logic in the order these items should be sorted, so I'd go with a list that defines the order for the sorting.

```js
let order = ["san jose", "new york", "chicago", "new jersey"];

var details = [{
    "name": "john",
    "place": "new york"
  },
  {
    "name": "mark",
    "place": "chicago"
  },
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "place": "san jose"
  },
  {
    "name": "dansk",
    "place": "new jersey"
  }]
  .sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a.place) - order.indexOf(b.place));
  
console.log(details);
```